# Network output gets Error 2501 The OutputTo action was canceled"

Tags: ms-access-2007

For at least 4 years this has been working fine for us, no issues.  We use the OutputTo command for a report, give the objectname, the format as PDF and then the network filepath of where it is supposed to be output.

A couple of months ago it was failing with the Error 2501 message.

My helpdesk has abandoned me on this so I was wondering if theres anyone out there who knows why this all of a sudden stopped working.

I created a simple, stripped out Access DB that does two things, outputs to the C drive and then outputs to the filepath based on a text box on a form.  That way i can test both UNC and network mapped name for the output.  Here is the line of code for the output:

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "TestReport", acFormatPDF, txtLocation.Value

Here are the facts....

1. It ONLY fails when outputing to the network.  I can use the code to output to a local drive without issue.
2. It will fail for both the UNC file path and the mapped drive name
3. Again - this code worked for years without any issues.
4. I am not the only user, I have tested the simple code in different machines, in different locations in the building.  It doesnt work anywhere.
5. We are using Access 2007.  It also doesnt work for users who just have the runtime dll for Access DB.
6. This is frustrating.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can Access see the network share at all?

Comment: Have you tested this - Is Adobe fully installed in the computers you are running the tests? acFormatPDF was introduced in 2007 so make sure if the systems you are running on have 2007 or higher. Never tested it in Runtime, so I cannot put my finger on that issue. Finally check if the path really exists before outputting, that also includes the **FileName**

Comment: I can export excel spreadsheets to the network yes.  All systems are running 2007 and the filepath exists.

Because it can output to a local drive leads me to think that its not a software issue.  

Could it be an issue with Adobe XI?  I use Adobe Pro, but other users have just standard Adobe XI reader.  It doesnt work for either of us.

Is there anyway I can upload the Access db?  You will see just how "basic" it truly is, only testing the OutputTo command.

Answer (score 0):

I went around the office and found two people that it works ok for.  This suggest to me there are group permissions preventing anyone in my "group" from outputting to the network.  These two people have no problem creating a PDF on any network location.